# Block positions

Tags: html, css

I am recently new to CSS and HTML and I have a problem while allocating my block under the header:

[image]

I have tried several solutions but I have not succeed. I would appreciate if you could give me a hint with it. Thanks

```
<!  DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title goes here</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Description of your site goes here">
  <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
    <div class="header" >
    <h1>  
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" width="250" height="190" float="right" />  
        <p> SOME TEXT HERE </p>
    </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="topmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What's&nbsp;New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS CODE:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif,Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:#d9d7d7;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, form, input, textarea {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
}
a {
    color: #072FCF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #072FCF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-out {
    background-image: url(../images/trans.png);
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.page {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    padding: 42px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: center;
}   
.header {
    position:absolute; 
    top:42px; 
    margin-left:-500px; 
    left:50%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid solid none solid;
    border-width: thick;    
}
.header h1{
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;

}
.header img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.header p {
    line-height: 190px; /* Here is the trick... line-height = image height */
}
.topmenu {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 37px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.topmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 37px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.topmenu ul li {
    height: 37px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.topmenu ul li a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 37px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 21px;
    padding-left: 21px;
}
.topmenu ul li a:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-hov.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is your topmenu at the end of your body? In terms of SEO and web crawlers it makes sense for this to be right at the top

Comment: Also you are missing a closing `</div>` tag

Comment: Why is the topmenu div listed second in the html? If you want it at the top, I'd think it should be listed first.

Comment: Also `position: center;` isn't valid

Comment: Also stop using absolute positioning

Comment: I want it just under the logo and Some text

Comment: if you remove all of your absolute positioning I think you will be much closer to the result you want

Comment: But hten everything is shifted to the left without any margin on this side. Why is this?

Comment: Because that is the default behavior?

Comment: Also, you have used `float: left;` on what I am assuming is your page wrapper (`.page` - the closing `</div>` tag is missing) - do you know that that does? You also have `position: center` which is invalid CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made several changes to your html/css:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:#d9d7d7;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, form, input, textarea {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
}
a {
    color: #072FCF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #072FCF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-out {
    background-image: url(../images/trans.png);
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.page {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid solid none solid;
    border-width: thick;
}
.header h1 {
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
}
.header img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.header p {
    line-height: 190px;
    /* Here is the trick... line-height = image height */
}
.topmenu {
    position:relative;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 37px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
.topmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 37px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.topmenu ul li {
    height: 37px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.topmenu ul li a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 37px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 21px;
    padding-left: 21px;
}
.topmenu ul li a:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/menu-hov.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
                <div class="topmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About&nbsp;Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">What's&nbsp;New</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
             <h1>  
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" width="250" height="190" float="right" />  
        <p> SOME TEXT HERE </p>
    </h1>

        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand three things to improve your html & css skills:

- Always follow natural stacking order (first element in html will
  display before second element...),
- Don't use `position: absolute`
  except if you know what you are doing as @Billy said,
- Use html5 tags if you don't need to support IE8 and below. If you do, then use HTML5
  Shiv to make them compatible.

Now here is a valid code that is also responsive (it will resize to your browser's viewport size). I have added a lot of comments in the code so that you can easily understand.

Good luck with your project!

```css
.page {
  width: 100%; /* Makes the page responsive */
  max-width: 1000px; /* all the content inside this div will be 1000 px width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* To center your page div in the page */
}
.topmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.topmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 14.2857142%; /* 100 / 7 (number of menu items) */
  background-color: #000;
  font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.topmenu ul li a:hover {
  /* As a general rule, never use images for hovers */
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.topmenu:after { /* This is a clearfix to clear your floated elements */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
header img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 190px;
}
header h1 {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  vertical-align: top; /* if you want the text to start at the top of the picture. Otherwise try middle or bottom */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <!-- always start with the first element on your page: here it's your navigation -->
  <nav class="topmenu"> <!-- use html5 tags. If you need to support IE8 or below you can use HTML5 Shiv -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What's&nbsp;New</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header> <!-- same, use html5 tags -->
    <!-- As a general rule, css is for styling not html so don't put any width, height or style in img tag -->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x190" alt="your picture description"/> <!-- always use alt text in images for accessibility purposes -->
    <h1>SOME TEXT HERE</h1>
  </header>
</div> <!-- don't forget this div that closes your .page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your absolute positioning (and add in the missing `</div>` tag to finish the `.page` div - I'm assuming this is wrapping all of your content inside).

To center your content, replace your `.page` CSS rule with this:

```
.page{
  width: 1000px; // I would reccommend using 960px instead as it is more standard
  margin: 0 auto;
  //add your padding in if you need it
}
```

Don't use absolute positioning until you understand it and why/how/when you should use it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rearrange your HTML markup.It doesn't seem like you are using the proper nested rule.I suggest you try to remove the img tag outside the h1 tag.Your div with class = "page" doesn't have a ending tag.